# Data Synchronizing in C#

Tags: c#, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

i have added this code in the page load event and the data in the local database is synchronizing to server database but i am not getting back the values which are in server database.

i have also added the code in LocalDataCache1.sync as mentioned in the forum and changed the database.sdf to "Do Not Copy".

The data from server is filling in Tableadapter but it is not updating local database.

```
 void HomeLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        clientBindingSource.EndEdit();
        tableAdapterManager1.UpdateAll(this.DataSet);            

        // Call SyncAgent.Synchronize() to initiate the synchronization process.
        // Synchronization only updates the local database, not your project’s data source.

        LocalDataCache1SyncAgent syncAgent = new LocalDataCache1SyncAgent();
        syncAgent.tbl_Miscellaneous.SyncDirection = Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncDirection.Bidirectional;
        Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncStatistics syncStats = syncAgent.Synchronize();

        //TODO: Reload your project data source from the local database (for example, call the TableAdapter.Fill method).
        miscellaneousTableAdapter1.Update(DataSet.Miscellaneous);
        miscellaneousTableAdapter1.Fill(DataSet.Miscellaneous);            
        DataSet.Miscellaneous.Merge(this.miscellaneousTableAdapter1.GetData());
    }
```

Comment: just to clarify, changes in your local database is reflected in the server but changes in the server is not synched back to your client?

Comment: Yes you are right JuneT, i am getting same kind of changes as you mentioned.

Comment: try subscribing to the ApplyChangeFailed event and see if there are errors applying changes from server or subscribe to the ChangesSelected event on the server side and confirm if the changes are even selected.

Comment: Hi,After adding all the code i am getting an error like "Value cannot be null.The error exists in this code "  Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncStatistics syncStats = syncAgent.Synchronize();"
Parameter name: ServerSyncProvider" so what is this error does anybody know.

Comment: can you post the actual stack trace?

Comment: But where can i find the ApplyChangeFailed event of LocalDataCache1SyncAgent.I have added the code like this in LocalDataCache1SyncAgent.cs, using System.Data;

namespace TrackVerifySystem {
    
    
    public partial class LocalDataCache1SyncAgent {

        partial void OnInitialized()
        {
            this.tbl_sync_test.SyncDirection = Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncDirection.Bidirectional;
        }
    }
}

Comment: it should be in the generated code..see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726009(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: This is where i synchronize the database,,,,, this.Validate();
            this.clientBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tbl_sync_testTableAdapter1.Fill(this.ds.tbl_sync_test);
            this.tableAdapterManager1.UpdateAll(this.Dataset1);

            LocalDataCache1SyncAgent syncAgent = new LocalDataCache1SyncAgent();           
            Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncStatistics syncStats = syncAgent.Synchronize();

            Dataset1.tbl_sync_test.Merge(tbl_sync_testTableAdapter1.GetData()); and also i have given LocalDataCache1.sync for client nserver, and a GUID in table.

Comment: LocalDataCache1SyncAgent  is a generated code. you can find inside it where the client and server providers are set. and if you use the link i posted above,  you should be able to set the event handlers.

Comment: Hi Manju..have you able to solve this issue/..?

Answer (score -1):

It will not get updated to your local DB automatically.
You need to manually add this using datatables,datasets of the replicated server DB.

Comment: why would you need a sync framework if you're going to add the records manually? did you even read the question?